# Title and button placement in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Sorry for the not-so-pretty code, but this is just a quick example of the problem I have.

I want the questions and buttons to be underneath each other, it works fine as long as the buttons are not next to each other like here:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
v = IntVar()
Label(root, text= "1st question", justify=LEFT).pack(padx=10)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button1",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=0).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="Button2",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=1).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="Button3",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=2).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="Button4",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=3).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="Button5",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=4).pack()

b = IntVar()
Label(root, text= "2nd question", justify=LEFT).pack(padx=10)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button1",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=0).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="Button2",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=1).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="Button3",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=2).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="Button4",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=3).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="Button5",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=4).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm sure there is something simple I've missed, you can have a look at the code I currently have:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
v = IntVar()
Label(root, text= "1st question", justify=LEFT).pack(side=TOP, padx=10)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button1",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=0).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button2",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=1).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button3",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=2).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button4",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=3).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button5",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=4).pack(side=LEFT)

b = IntVar()
Label(root, text= "2nd question", justify=LEFT).pack(side=TOP, padx=10)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button1",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=0).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button2",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=1).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button3",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=2).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button4",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=3).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(root, text="Button5",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=b, value=4).pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Consider creating radiobutton widgets with a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Put the buttons in a Frame, and then pack the Frame normally.

```
Label(root, text= "1st question", justify=LEFT).pack(padx=10)
buttonframe = Frame(root)
Radiobutton(buttonframe, text="Button1",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=0).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(buttonframe, text="Button2",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=1).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(buttonframe, text="Button3",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=2).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(buttonframe, text="Button4",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=3).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(buttonframe, text="Button5",indicatoron = 0, width = 10, variable=v, value=4).pack(side=LEFT)
buttonframe.pack()
```